# run jedit single command from terminal linux

Tags: linux, jedit

I'm trying to run jedit from the terminal on fedora. its installed to the path /usr/local/share....
How do I get it to run "jedit" from the terminal rather than switching to the directory and typing java -jar jedit.jar to execute the program.

I created a sh file in that same direectory with "java -jar jedit.jar" and added that directory to ~/.bashrc. I'm aware that I need to type "sh file.sh" to run that file but I know there is a gap in my knowledge somewhere.

i want to use jedit as a commit editor for git and be able to change core.editor='jedit -w' in git config
someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you used the Java installer?

If this is the case, the installer should also have placed a `jedit` launch script in `/usr/local/bin` which should be in your `PATH` by default, so calling `jedit` from a terminal should instantly work after installation.

If it does not work, then please check whether the file `jedit` is available in `/usr/local/bin` and whether `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Unchecking the "API Documentation (for macro and plugin development)" in Choose components to install seemed to have fixed it. I appreciate the help from everyone

Comment: Are you sure this wasn't a coincidence? I don't think this option should influence whether the launch script gets installed. If this is really the case, you should file a bug report. If not, it would be nice if you accept my answer.